# Need to replace a specific part of line from a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to replace the `path` part of below line from postgresql.conf using shell script:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'      # use data in another directory
```

I first checked if I'm able to locate the line first using below script, but it did not find the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        if [[ "$line" = "data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'         # use data in another directory" ]]
```

I know there is better way to replace this line using `sed`, but I need to know if its doable by reading the file from start to end and then replace the desired part of the line, if found. If not, replacing the entire line with only the `path` part changed will do it too. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's doable in plain bash (but not recommended). Use parameter expansion, for instance `${var/find/replace}`.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you are asking, "How can I avoid `sed`" or "`sed` is okay but I do not know how." I have answered the latter.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @tbh, I know how to do it by `sed` but I want to do it using loop and all because I'm not familiar with it and I know loop will be useful for me in other scenarios as well. Learning!

Comment: There are more spaces before `#` in the string you're comparing with `$line` than the line you gave as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using `case` - `*`'s allow non-exact spacing around the equals and before any comment, but introduce the small possibility of false matches. I think with the rest of the specific info on the line it's small enough that it isn't a problem.

```
$: cat postgresql.conf
some stuff
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'         # use data in another directory
some other stuff.

$: path=/new/path/to/
$: while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
>  do case "$line" in
>     data_directory*=*'/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'*) 
>        echo "${line//\/*\//$path}";;
>     *) echo "$line";;
>     esac
>  done < postgresql.conf >/tmp/checkme
some stuff
data_directory = '/new/path/to/main'         # use data in another directory
some other stuff.
```

If it's good, then

```
mv /tmp/checkme postgresql.conf
```

You could test it a few times, and then just make it automatic, but unless it's an ongoing automation that you're building I'd check it personally.

Comment: This worked. Thanks! I added `> postgresql.conf` at the end of the command to have this path change written into the file permanently. But the .conf file simply became empty with all the content gone. Of course it was a duplicate file I was working on,but this was a good lesson. Would you suggest any other way (using same logic as in your answer) to make this change permanent?

Comment: That's because the shell opens (and truncates) `postgresql.conf` for writing before it ever starts to read from the file. You need to write to a temporary file first, then move it into place after you are done.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect!! This not only solves the problem, but explains a lot of things to a novice like me.

Answer (score 3):

Plain bash solution:

```
path="/newpath"
while IFS= read -r -d $'\n'; do
  if [[ "${REPLY}" == "data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'      # use data in another directory" ]]
  then echo "${REPLY/\'*\'/'${path}'}"
  else echo "${REPLY}"
  fi
done < postgresql.conf > new.conf

mv new.conf postgresql.conf
```

Test:

```
$ cat postgresql.conf
# This is a comment
log_connections = yes
log_destination = 'syslog'
search_path = '"$user", public'
shared_buffers = 128MB
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'      # use data in another directory
# This is a comment

$ path="/newpath"
$ while IFS= read -r -d $'\n'; do
>   if [[ "${REPLY}" == "data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'      # use data in another directory" ]]
>   then echo "${REPLY/\'*\'/'${path}'}"
>   else echo "${REPLY}"
>   fi
> done < postgresql.conf

# This is a comment
log_connections = yes
log_destination = 'syslog'
search_path = '"$user", public'
shared_buffers = 128MB
data_directory = '/newpath'      # use data in another directory
# This is a comment
```

Comment: This is really insightful. However, the result I get is `data_directory = ${path}`. Not the path assigned to `path` variable. I literally copy pasted. Nevertheless, +1 for insightful details.

Answer (score 1):

```
REPLACEMENT_PATH=mypath
sed -i path/postgresql.conf -re "s/^(data_directory[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*')[^']*(')/\1${REPLACEMENT_PATH}\2/"
```

Comment: @tbh, thank you for sharing, but I want to know the way to do it by reading the file from start to end using while loop as mentioned in the question. What mistake do you see in my `if` condition, which is causing it not to find the line?